# Iterating through a for loop and saving the retrieved data in a unique csv file for each loop | Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, for-loop

I'm new to python and I'm trying to retrieve stock data using a for loop and then save that information as a dataframe to then save as `.csv`. Basically, I'm creating a `custom_stock_data` function that will pass the `ticker_list` (containing the stock symbols). I then want each item on this list to be passed through the `for` loop so that the data can be saved as a dataframe in the variable `ticker_data` and save it as `.csv`. I then do `ticker_data += 1` to move to the next csv file (I don't know if this is how you can do it, any help is welcome!)

This is the code:

```
def custom_stock_data (ticker):
    ticker_data = []
    for symbol in ticker:
        ticker_data = pd.DataFrame(get_data(symbol, start_date = "05/25/2021", end_date = "07/30/2021", interval = "1wk"))
        ticker_data.to_csv(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\estagio\data_{}.csv".format(symbol))
    ticker_data += 1
    print(ticker_data)

ticker_list = ["AMZN", "TSLA", "AAPL"]
custom_stock_data(ticker_list)
```

I am also only getting the last information on my `ticker_list` (which would be AAPL). I can't seem to be getting the information on the first two tickers, as shown in the picture

[image: APPL stock]

Thank you!

Comment: `ticker_data` is a dataframe, why do you think `ticker_data += 1` will go to the next csv file?

Comment: You have `print(ticker_data)` outside the loop. So it's just printing the last value.

Comment: I see, so maybe I could do ticker_csv = [] and then do ticker_csv = ticker_data.to_csv and then do the ticker_csv +=1?

Comment: A bit confusing, is your code producing three csvs with different names (data_APPL) that only have APPL data?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just remove`ticker_data = []`, `ticker_data += 1` and `print(ticker_data)`. The CSV files will be generated without those 3 lines since there is no need to accumulate the data in a list if you only need separate CSVs.

Also, one possible reason why you're getting only information for `AAPL` (the last ticker in your list) is because the function `get_data()` might have `AAPL` hard-coded in it somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Take out `ticker_data = []`. It's useless because you reassign the variable inside the loop.

`ticker_data += 1` is not needed. `for symbol in ticker:` goes to the next symbol automatically each time through the loop.

If you want to see each dataframe, put `print(ticker_data)` inside the loop.

```
def custom_stock_data (ticker):
    for symbol in ticker:
        ticker_data = pd.DataFrame(get_data(symbol, start_date = "05/25/2021", end_date = "07/30/2021", interval = "1wk"))
        ticker_data.to_csv(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\estagio\data_{}.csv".format(symbol))
        print(ticker_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit confusing, I guess that could help you try to debug the issue, print the actual symbol you are working with, and before you save the CSV check the value that is being saved in the column ticker, will not solve but let me know the output:

```
def custom_stock_data (ticker):
    ticker_data = []
    for symbol in ticker:
        print(f"Working with {symbol}")
        ticker_data = pd.DataFrame(get_data(symbol, start_date = "05/25/2021", end_date = "07/30/2021", interval = "1wk"))
        print(f"Value in CSV is {ticker_data['ticker'].unique()}")            
        ticker_data.to_csv(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\estagio \data_{}.csv".format(symbol))
    ticker_data += 1
    print(ticker_data)

ticker_list = ["AMZN", "TSLA", "AAPL"]
custom_stock_data(ticker_list)
```